# sed error: unterminated address regex - bash script

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am getting two different errors from sed when running them in a bash script. Some of the command seem to work, even so? It does not seem to do this when run directly.

`sed -ibak -r -e "/^(# )?export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=[0-9]+/ s/^(# )?//" ~/.zshrc`

> sed: -e expression #1, char : unterminated address regex

and

`sed -ibak -r -e "/^ZSH_THEME=/ s/ZSH_THEME=\".*\"/ZSH_THEME=\"themename\"/" ~/.zshrc`

> sed: -e expression #1, char 13: missing command

Comment: The `-f` option is to specify a file with sed commands. You should remove it if you just want to apply the substitution to `~/.zhrc`.

Comment: thanks, this has solved the second issue and introduced yet another error. Post edited.

Comment: ...you're using bash to edit a zsh config file? If your shell is really zsh, you should be tagging appropriately. (Not that it matters in this very specific case, but it matters in general).

Comment: Any reason you don't want to edit the .zshrc file in your editor and be done with it?  Try using the single quote (to prevent filename expansion) to quote your sed expression.

Comment: `sed -i.bak 's/ZSH_THEME="[^"]*"/ZSH_THEME="themename"/' ~/.zshrc`

Comment: BTW, if you want to run multiple `sed` commands, pass each one after a separate `-e`.

Comment: it's a script to install and configure zsh on servers so bash is needed here, short of installing zsh with bash and calling another zsh script

Comment: Certainly can be done like this, just wanted to be sure you weren't misrepresenting which shell you were using. We get a lot of zsh questions tagged "bash", and it's a thing that I've gotten a little grumpy about. (Not, again, that this one is really shell-specific at all).

Comment: @anubhava good shout with the [^"] but i'm still getting `missing command`

Comment: Can't reproduce the errors. What is your version of sed?

Comment: no error is produced if I remove the line selection

Comment: @Leon 4.2.2 on Ubuntu 16.04.1

Comment: @Leon i'm actually inserting the expression into sed with a variable. The command being run is `$exp="EXPRESSION"` and `sed -i.bak -r -e $exp ~/.zshrc`.

Comment: That explains it! You must quote your variable expansion: `sed -i.bak -r -e "$exp" ~/.zshrc`

Comment: Just copy/paste this command in your shell and see what you get: `sed 's/ZSH_THEME="[^"]*"/ZSH_THEME="themename"/' ~/.zshrc`

Comment: And no need to use `-r` or `-e` actually for this command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note to self: don't try to simplify the problem when asking it on SO.

I was using a variable to insert the expression into sed and didn't quote it.

`sed -i.bak -r -e "$exp" ~/.zshrc`

as per Leon's comment